# Preg_Replace_Callback replacing matched items with Array

Tags: php, twitter, preg-replace-callback

I created a replace function to identify twitter accounts and I want to create a link to my internal pages if I have that twitter account present in my data.

```
//Creates a link for users
    $tester = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\s+@(\w+)/',
      "BrewIdFinder",
    $tester );


function BrewIdFinder($matches){
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT brew_id FROM places WHERE screen_name = '".$matches."' LIMIT 1");
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result3);
        if($num_rows==0){
        $x= '<a href="http://twitter.com/'.$matches.'" target="_new">@'.$matches.'</a>';
        }else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
       {
        $brewid= $row['brew_id'];
       }
        $x= '<a href="http://www.brewzinga.com/places/'.$brewid.'" target="_new">@'.$matches.'</a>';
         }
return $x;
}
```

I get a return for each Twitter Screenname as Array.  Can I get some help figuring out what is wrong?

Comment: is `$tester` an array?

Comment: $tester is a string.  It's the tweet i am trying to parse through to find the @screenname to replace with a link.

Comment: I added an array for matches[0] in the code and that fixed the problem.  For some reason it passes multiple matches.  Maybe I needed to specify the number of count to test for in the string.

Comment: That is expected behavior is $tester is an array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it.  I had to specify which match to review. Thanks for the help.

```
function BrewIdFinder($matches){
$sweet= substr($matches[0], 2);
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT brew_id FROM places WHERE screen_name like '".$sweet."'");
    $num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($result3);
    if($num_rows1==0){
    $x= ' <a href="http://twitter.com/'.$sweet.'" target="_new">@'.$sweet.'</a>';
    }else{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
  {
   $brewid= $row['brew_id'];
  }
    $x= ' <a href="http://www.brewzinga.com/places/'.$brewid.'" target="_new">@'.$sweet.'</a>';
         }
return $x;
}
```